# Google spreadsheet analytics automatically sorting

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet issue, I have an analytics sheet (sheet A) with url entries.

The data from that sheet (sheet A) is stored in a different sheet (sheet B) 
Now I want to the URLS + NUMBERS automatically sorted on the numbers in sheet B.

I have extracted them with success, but I can't use the spreadsheet sort option because the data is generated and changes every day which means the sort option resets when it recieves new info.

I've tried this query :

```
=QUERY(a:b , "SELECT * ORDER BY b")
```

I've looked for a Google script but I have 3 columns:

Entry    | Exit    | General

- Sheet A

  [image: Sheet A]
- Sheet B

  [image: Sheet B]
- Sheet B, after `View > All formulas`

  [image: Sheet B formulas]

Comment: Your query command would work if it included column C in the data. `=QUERY(sheetA!a:C , "SELECT * ORDER BY C") `

Comment: It returns : circular dependency detected

Comment: If your data is in sheet A, you have to put Mogsdad's formula in Sheet B

Comment: Already doing that. Sheet A is the sheet which stores the result from the analytics plug-in , Sheet B is the sheet where I format the info from Sheet A. I have added images for more info

Comment: What formulas are you using and where? Can you click on View-> All Formulas, and paste screenshots?

Comment: Also you cannot run a query if there are values in the cells where the query will be pasted

Comment: As requested an image from sheet B : http://puu.sh/ijkYO/71eac37407.png

Comment: Query needs space to put data. At the moment it is surrounded by other formulas. You have to delete those formulas, and just keep the Query

Comment: Also shouldn't your formula be =QUERY('Landing oud'!A16:B , "SELECT * ORDER BY B")   Basicaly, you have to query your original data, otherwise you are trying to run a query of itself, which does not make sense

Comment: You were right. I was thinking the other way. First the data then the query but that was wrong :)

Thank you for the fast response !

Comment: I have wrote a separate answer, please check set it as correct.

Comment: @AkshinJalilov & SirJord: great resolution, although working through the problem in comments indicates that the question wasn't clear to begin with. (It's received a number of close votes.) When you find yourself in a comments-conversation like this, _improve the question_. It was good to add images - but better would have been to put all clarifying info right in the question, and use comments to say "question updated", perhaps with an "at"\[helpful-person-name] added to notify them. Akshin - don't be afraid to ask someone to update their question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshots you want the sorted data to be in **Total Results D12:E** and your original data is in **Landing oud!A16:B**.

In order to do that, delete everything in range **Total Results D12:E**. Then, in cell **Total Results D12** enter the following formula

```
=QUERY('Landing oud'!A16:B , "SELECT * ORDER BY B")
```